# How to get CONNECT response headers with C# HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, https

The following code uses C# HttpWebRequest to fetch a page from an HTTPS site and print the headers in the response:

```
var Request = WebRequest.Create("https://google.com") as HttpWebRequest;
WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(Response.Headers);
```

Since this request uses HTTPS, the C# library automatically sends a CONNECT message to set up an SSL tunnel before sending the GET message. I've set up System.Net tracing and I can see in the log (too long to include) a CONNECT request and response preceding the GET request and response, but that initial exchange seems to be hidden from the HttpWebRequest level.

What comes back in the WebResponse object is only the headers from the response to the GET message. What I want to see is the headers in the response to the CONNECT message. How do I do this?